# spring-boot project with spring-security do not access views

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I start a new project based on spring-boot, using this working configuration class for spring-security from another project:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .csrf()
            .disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
          .and()
          .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
          handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
          web.expressionHandler(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

when I deploy the project in the tomcat server, without errors, and try access the application, instead of the index page, I get a popup windows asking me for username and password.

the full code for the project is: https://github.com/klebermo/basic_webapp

anyone can see what's wrong with this configuration?

Comment: I suggest a read of the documentation. In short add `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` to your configuration class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your application.properties file:

`security.basic.enabled=false`

By default everything is secured with HTTP Basic authentication.

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.html